# Función no funciona adecuadamente (devuelve siempre "False")

Tags: python, function

Estoy resolviendo un ejercicio de Python sobre un programa que tiene que devolver "False", en caso de que el carácter introducido sea consonante, y "True", en caso de que sea vocal. El problema es que la función siempre me devuelve "False", sin importar lo que escribo.

Este es el código:

```
vowels=['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

def is_vowel(char):
    if str(char).lower in vowels:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(is_vowel(input("Type a vowel or a consonant: ")))
```

Como pueden observar, el valor que le paso a la función es un input. De esta manera, el usuario puede introducir un carácter, el cual será guardado en el parámetro de entrada de la función (char).

He creado una lista para que así la función pueda comprobar si el carácter introducido se encuentra dentro de la lista. Si se encuentra dentro de la lista, entonces es vocal, si no, entonces es consonante.

Les agradecería mucho que me ayudaran con este problema.

Comment: Buen día, has publicado tu pregunta en el sitio de [es.so], la pregunta está en un idioma que no es el oficial en este sitio y por lo tanto puede ser cerrada o votada negativamente. Te recomiendo que leas la sección [ask]. Puedes traducir tu pregunta o publicarla en el sitio de Stack Overflow en inglés.

Comment: Y el error es que la función `lower` necesita los paréntesis y no hace falta convertir `char` a `string`, así `if char.lower() in vowels:`

Comment: Muchas gracias! He traducido el texto a español. Perdón por las molestias!

Comment: Es mejor que quites el texto en inglés y traduzcas el título también ya que las preguntas en [es.so] que no están en el idioma oficial que es el español terminan cerradas. De igual forma puse la respuesta en el comentario anterior. Saludos!

Comment: Okay! Voy a quitar lo que está puesto inglés! Muchas gracias!

Comment: No hay de que, si viste y entendiste la respuesta que puse en el segundo comentario?

Comment: Sí, lo entendí a la perfección. Estoy empezando en Python y espero poder convertirme en un ingeniero de ciberseguridad, por lo que cometo muchos errores. Muchas gracias por tu  aportación

Comment: Perfecto, algo que me ha ayudado a aprender más es practicar con las preguntas que hacen los usuarios aquí, guarda la etiqueta de `Python` y lee las preguntas, revisa las respuestas, eso te va a ayudar mucho. Si quieres acortar tu función a una sola línea puedes hacer esto `return True if char.lower() in 'aeiou' else False`. Esta pregunta posiblemente termine cerrada ya que se solucionó en los comentarios así que no te desanimes si eso sucede. Que tengas buen día!

Comment: Algo más sinplificado de lo que dijo @HeytalePazguato sería hacer `return char.lower() in 'aeiou"`

Comment: Ah hahaha claro, ya estaba comparando con el `in`. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que este es un ejercicio muy típico y plantea variados problemas, me extiendo un poco más allá que la pregunta.

Para trabajar con letras hay un módulo que te evita escribir todo el abcedario `from string import ascii_lowercase as abcd`. Ahora tienes todas las letras minúsculas en `abcd`.

El código que pretendes podría ser algo como:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as abcd

while True:
    letra =input("Escribe una vocal o una consonante ('salir' para salir): ").lower()
    if 'salir' == letra: break
    if len(letra) > 1 or letra not in abcd: continue
    resp = ('Es ' if letra in 'aeiou' else 'No es ') + 'una vocal'
    print(f'{letra} {resp}')
```

Lo primero compruebo que los datos del usuario son correctos u los paso a minúsculas.

Ahora podemos crear funciones, que es lo ideal.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as abcd

def is_vowel(char_):
    if char_.lower in 'aeiou': return True
    return False

while True:
    letra =input("Escribe una vocal o una consonante (salir para salir): ")
    if 'salir' == letra: break
    if len(letra) > 1 or letra.lower() not in abcd: continue
    resp = ('Es' if is_vowel(letra) else 'No es') + ' una vocal'
    print(f'{letra} {resp}')
```

En el código que planteas utilizas `char` que es una función del programa.
Lo puedes cambiar para evitar posibles problemas simplemente añadiendo el guión bajo.

La mejor opción (creo yo) sería validar todo desde la función.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as abcd

def es_vocal(char_):
    if 'salir' == letra.lower(): return 0
    if len(letra) > 1 or letra.lower() not in abcd: return -1
    return 1 if char_ in 'aeiou' else 2


resp = ['Salimos del programa', 'es vocal', 'es consonante', 'No es válido']
while True:
    letra =input("Escribe una vocal o una consonante (salir para salir): ")
    solucion = es_vocal(letra)
    if solucion == 0:
        print(resp[solucion])
        break
    print(f'{letra} {resp[solucion]}')
```

La función devuelve diversos valores más allá del `True / False` con lo que imprimes y ejecutas según el resultado.

En este caso el valor 0 para *salir*, el -1 es valor *no válido* y 1 y 2 `True / False`.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por ir más allá de la pregunta! Sin duda, tu respuesta me ha ayudado bastante a comprender mejor todo.

Answer (score 1):

Las llamadas a función van con un `()`. Si ocupas el nombre de la función sin usar paréntesis, no la estas **llamando** si no recuperando el objeto función, que obviamente no es una vocal, ni letra ni caracter.

Solución:

```
def is_vowel(letra):
    return letra.lower() in "aeiou"

print(is_vowel(input("Type a vowel or a consonant: ")))
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!